# Upgrade RDLC from 2008 to 2010 (2005 report to 2008 report) Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have multiple reports that have been created over the years and anytime a RDLC file is opened in the VS2010, it is asking for an upgrade. I have seen many posts about changing the .config file, but these files are not using config files since they are application based. I have Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms, .Common, .ProcessingObjectModel and, .WebForms 9.0 and 8.0 installed on the lab machine.

After upgrading a report and trying to run it on the lab machine ( ms server 2008) I am returned an error of: "The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

Does Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package fix this issue? I cannot find a distinct answer. If not, is there another workaround without changing server modes from local to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be opening those using the SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS), which can be found under the Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2 folder on the Programs menu.

Comment: There is another way as well. Microsoft released http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6610 which the way it seems to work is that version 10.0.0.0 is for vs 2010 and of course 9.0.0.0 is for VS 2008. 

I saw a lot of issues with people not able to make the changes if there wasn't a .config file. Update your references in the original app so that it calls to the correct report dll. The update needs to be installed on both the dev machine and the machine the applications will be running on.